# Generic Java REST endpoint - how to check that provided typ and object parameters are actually of the same typ

Tags: java, generics, quarkus

I have a question regarding the following issue:

I'm trying to create a generic REST endpoint that will accept subclasses of a given typ.
Before working with the object, I want to confirm that it is of the type stated by the client.

**The code:**

***Endpoint***

```
    @POST
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response sampleEndpoint(@PathParam("id") IdType idType, IdBaseDto<IdBaseClass> idDto) {
     return idService.createItemWithId(idType, idDto);
}
```

***Enum***

```
public enum IdType {
  FIRST(SAMPLE_ONE.class),
  SECOND(SAMPLE_TWO.class),
  THIRD(SAMPLE_THREE.class),

  private final Class<? extends IdBaseClass> idClass;

  // rest omitted

}
```

***DTO***

```
public class IdBaseDto<T extends IdBaseClass> {

@NotNull
private T config;

// rest omitted

}
```

In the `createItemWithId` method I want to check if the given `id` - respective its `idClass`- is of the same type as the `idDto` declared as `IdBaseDto<IdBaseClass>`.

I tried playing around with `idDto.getConfig().getClass()` etc., but of course this returns the `IdBaseClass`, declared as a type in the generic.

**Question**

Is there an easy - beginner friendly- way to perform a check like this given the described scenario?

Comment: Search for `jackson polymorphism`. There are a lot of articles on the subject, perhaps not so beginner friendly.

Comment: Thank you, will check!